# VS2010 save array/collection data to a file while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Is there some way to save array/list/collection data to a file while debugging in VS2010?

For example, in this code:

```
var addressGraphs = from a in context.Addresses
                    where a.CountryRegion == "Canada"
                    select new { a, a.Contact };

foreach(var ag in addressGraphs) {
   Console.WriteLine("LastName: {0}, Addresses: {1}", ag.Contact.LastName.Trim(),
                     ag.Contact.Addresses.Count());



   foreach(var Address in ag.Contact.Addresses) {
      Console.WriteLine("...{0} {1}", Address.Street1, Address.City);
   }
}
```

I'd like to set a breakpoint on the first 'foreach' line and then save the data in 'addressGraph' to a file.

where 'a' contains fields such as:

```
   int addressID
   string Street1
   string City
   <Ect.>
```

and 'Contact' contains fields such as:

```
   string FirstName
   string LastName
   int contactID
   <Ect.>
```

I'd like the file to contain the values of each of the fields for each item in the collection.

I don't see an obvious way to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: To clarify, I need to be able to do this on the fly, on an arbitrary collection. Having to add code to the app does not meet my needs.

Answer (score 30):

When your breakpoint is hit, open up the `Immediate` window and use [Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x72c7xc8.aspx) to dump the output to a file:

```
>Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput c:\temp\temp.log
?addressGraphs
>Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput /off
```

**Note:** You can use `Log` which is an alias for `Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput`

---

**Update:**
The `>` character is important. Also, the `log` alias is case sensitive.
See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get 'Log' to work in the immediate window, but it does work in the command window.

Comment: @casterle: Did you type `>` character? That's important. That character tells the Immediate window that you're entering a command.

Comment: I couldn't get 'Log' to work in the immediate window, but it does work in the command window. In either window the ? command displays:

`code`
{System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Chapter_2_Console_App.Contact>}
    base {System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery}: {System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Chapter_2_Console_App.Contact>}
    _name: "it"
    Name: "it"
`code`

but does not display the contents of the collection. What am I missings?

Comment: I did not - I thought the '>' was a command prompt. As you suggested, typing the '>' fixed the Log issue. Is there more I need to do to make the '?' command work?

Comment: The `?` does not do deep serialization. The easiest way is to say `?code.[Collection]` to display the contents of collection. (Note I used fake names but you get idea)

Comment: I'm starting to feel like an idiot here; I don't seem to be able to get this to work. Is `?code` a command? That doesn't appear to the case because `?code.addressGraphs` results in a complaint that 'code' does not exist. What exactly does `code` represent? The answer must be obvious but it escapes me.

Comment: I got 'code' from your previous comment: "The easiest way is to say ?code.[Collection]". Typing ?addressGraphs takes us back to the third comemnt above; I don't get the data.

Comment: And I got code from your previous comment :). You missed the fake names part in my comment. If you need `addressGraph` and the contents of all its child objects, you need to serialize `addressGraph`. This is not so trivial (but not so difficult either). It means you need to punch in few more commands and the class for `addressGraph` must be marked as serializable. Take a look at this article which explains serialization: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/objserial.aspx

Comment: OK, now I get it, and your comment about serialization makes sense. BTW, the 'code' thing was my misuse of the backtick token. I was trying to get the code in my comment into a ‘code’ block so it would format correctly; I saw that (backtick-code-backtick) was used for this purpose, but thought it was supposed to surround the code block literally. That’s how ‘code’ came to appear in my comment twice .

Comment: I appreciate all the effort you put into this answer, but it doesn’t really solve my problem which is to be able to dump the contents of an arbitrary collection at debug time. I expect that there is no way to do this without writing some kind of VS extension using reflection (which is beyond my ken at this point). Thank you once again!

Comment: for c++ code this is giving output similar to following:

?addressGraphs

0x00000072dff967d0 ")#¾„álÖ®RIññ»é...

>Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput /off

how to make it save just contents of the array without the other info?

Answer (score 8):

I also encoutered such a question, but in VS2013. I have to save a content of array while debugging.

For example, I need to save a content of double array named "trimmedInput". I do so:

1. Open QuickWatch Window from Debug menu (Ctrl+D, Q).
   [image]
2. Put your variable in Expression and push Recalculate Button
   [image]
3. You'll see all the values. Now you could select them all (Ctrl+A) and copy (Ctrl+C).
4. Paste (Ctrl+V) them in your favorite editor. Notepad, for example. And use them.
   [image]

That's the simples way that I know. Without additional efforts. Hope that my description helps you!

P.S. Sorry for non English interface on screenshots. All necessary information are written in the text.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar is possible with this method:

I built an extension method that I use in all of my projects that is a general and more powerful ToString() method that shows the content of any object. 
I included the source code in this link:
https://rapidshare.com/files/1791655092/FormatExtensions.cs

**UPDATE:**
You just have to put FormatExtensions.cs in your project and change the Namespace of FormatExtensions to coincide to the base Namespace of your project. So when you are in your breakpoint you can type in your watch window:
myCustomCollection.ToStringExtended()

And copy the output wherever you want

Comment: This sounds interesting, and although it does require code, it does so in such a painless way that it would work for me. However, I'm new to the whole VS/C#/.NET thing and don't understand how to make this work in my project. Could you be more specific as to exactly how I can use your code?

Comment: This is the quickest way: Let's say you have a class library project called "MyClassLibrary", you put this code inside the class library and change the namespace of FormatExtensions to "MyClassLibrary". Now you will have the extension "ToStringExtended" in every object in your project.

Comment: Thanks, that made it easy. It works well, however (isn't there always a 'however'?) the result is a string that is 139,395(!) charcters long which isn't very useful, at least WRT what I'm trying to accomplish. I don't suppose there's a way to get the output formatted to resemble the structure of the data?

Comment: Everything is possible by coding it :). For me this formatting is fine as I mainly use it to write complex variables in log files. I just thought that this that you suggested might be another use. Let us know if you write a version with a more compact formatting.

Comment: I'll be sure to do that. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can also call methods in the Immediate Window, and so I think your best bet would be to use an ObjectDumper object, like [the one in the LINQ samples](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/25/all-about-objectdumper.aspx) or [this one](http://objectdumper.codeplex.com/), and then write something like this in the Immediate Window:

> File.WriteAllText("myFileName.txt", ObjectDumper.Dump(addressGraph));

Depending on which ObjectDumper you decide to use, you may be able to customize it to suit your needs, and to be able to tell it how many levels deep you want it to dig into your object when it's dumping it.

Comment: Both of these solutions require that I change my code before I can dump the collection.

Comment: well, not neccesarily, you could load it manually by calling Assembly.Load("ObjectDumper.dll") from the Immediate Window. BTW, why do you want to save it to file?

Comment: I'm interested in viewing the content of a collection at a point in time during debug. There are a couple of reasons I'd like to be able to dump to a file (especially for large amounts of data): 1) So I can peruse and search within the data, and 2) So I can diff the data between runs or at different points in the code.

Comment: Re ObjectDumper: it doesn't do what I'm looking for, dumping thousands of lines of arcane information but, as far as I can see, none of the collection field values I'm looking for.

Comment: Re ObjectDumper, that's strange, perhaps it's because addressGraphs is a collection of an anonymous type, and so the "arcane strings" you're seeing are the compiler generated names for the anonymous type and auto properties? In any case, I updated my answer with another option.

Answer (score 1):

On [Visual studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com) search for: **Object Exporter** Extension.
be aware: as far as I worked with, it has a bug that block you from exporting object once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that takes care of collections. It's a VS visualizer that will display the collection values in a grid while debugging as well as save to the clipboard and csv, xml and text files. I'm using it in VS2010 Ultimate. While I haven't tested it extensively, I have tried it on List and Dictionary.

http://tinyurl.com/87sf6l7

It handles the following collections:

```
•System.Collections classes  
   ◦System.Collections.ArrayList  
   ◦System.Collections.BitArray  
   ◦System.Collections.HashTable  
   ◦System.Collections.Queue  
   ◦System.Collections.SortedList  
   ◦System.Collections.Stack  
   ◦All classes derived from System.Collections.CollectionBase  

•System.Collections.Specialized classes  
   ◦System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary  
   ◦System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary  
   ◦System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection  
   ◦System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary  
   ◦System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection  
   ◦System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary  
   ◦All classes derived from System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase  

•System.Collections.Generic classes  
   ◦System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
   ◦System.Collections.Generic.List  
   ◦System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList  
   ◦System.Collections.Generic.Queue  
   ◦System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary  
   ◦System.Collections.Generic.SortedList  
   ◦System.Collections.Generic.Stack  

•IIS classes, as used by  
   ◦System.Web.HttpRequest.Cookies  
   ◦System.Web.HttpRequest.Files  
   ◦System.Web.HttpRequest.Form  
   ◦System.Web.HttpRequest.Headers  
   ◦System.Web.HttpRequest.Params  
   ◦System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString  
   ◦System.Web.HttpRequest.ServerVariables  
   ◦System.Web.HttpResponse.Cookies
```

As well as a couple of VB6-compatible collections

Answer (score 0):

In "Immediate Window" print following to get the binary dump:

```
byte[] myArray = { 02,01,81,00,05,F6,05,02,01,01,00,BA };

myArray
  .Select(b => string.Format("{0:X2}", b))
  .Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + s2)
```

This will print something like:

```
0201810005F60502010100BA
```

Change the '.Aggregate(...)' call to add blanks between bytes, or what ever you like.